# C syntax understanding - parameter passing to function

Tags: c, parameters

Here a header of a function:

```
int* matrixmult(const int*ap[], const int* bp[], int* cp[])
```

and the working call of the function:

```
matrixmult(ap, bp, cp);
```

Why doesn't this call work?:

```
matrixmult(ap[0], bp[0], cp[0]);
```

Comment: Because the function requires you passing an array not an item from that array. Perhaps read the book again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't this call work?:
>
> `matrixmult(ap[0], bp[0], cp[0]);`

Here, the values (first item of array - `int`) are passed to the function, while pointers are expected:

```
int* matrixmult(const int*ap[], const int* bp[], int* cp[])
```

This:

```
matrixmult(ap, bp, cp);
```

works because all three are pointers. `ap` is the same as `&ap[0]`.

Comment: @classMate - Yes, I just added that to the answer.